# Jekyll - Change _config.yml variables in the post layout

Tags: jekyll

In my `config.yml` I have:

```
...

showheader: "yes"
```

And in my `default.html` template I have a conditional to show the header include:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  {% include head.html %}
  <body>
    {% if site.showheader == "yes" %}{% include header.html %}{% endif %}
    <main class="page-main">
      {{ content }}
    </main>
    {% include footer.html %}
 </body>
</html>
```

In my `post.html` template I don't want to show the `header.html` so I try this:

```
---
layout: default
---
{{ site.showheader = "no" }}
<article class="post">
  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-h1" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <p class="post-meta">{{ page.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}{% if page.author %} • {{ page.author }}{% endif %}{% if page.meta %} • {{ page.meta }}{% endif %}</p>
  </header>
  <p class="post-p">{{ content }}</p>
  <footer class="post-footer">
    <p class="rss-subscribe">subscribe <a href="{{ "/feed.xml" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">via RSS</a></p>
  </footer>
</article>
```

But it's simple don't work,and neither returned a error.
It is possible in Jekyll to change the value of a variable set in `_config.yml` from the `post.html` template layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot reassign a `site.variable` value. `{% assign site.showheader = false %}` doesn't work if `showheader: true` is set in `_config.yml`.

If you want to show header depending on the page you're on, just set the variable in page front matter.

In index.html :

```
---
showheader: true
layout: default
---
```

In post :

```
---
showheader: false
layout: default
---
```

In _layouts/default.html

```
{% if page.showheader == true %}
    header
{% endif %}
```